# How can I convert a list of character numbers with commas integer into a list of integers?

Tags: python

So I have a list of characters that looks like the following;

```
a = ['243,243,143', '215,432', '325,213,541', '213,324', '235,234,214']
```

I want to convert this list to integer so it looks like this;

```
a = [243243143, 215432, 325213541, 213324, 235234214]
```

I have tried;

```
[int(int(a.replace(',',''))) for i in a]
```

but that returned an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: You are calling `a.replace` ... it should be `i.replace`, that should solve the error, but there are others still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
[int(a.replace(',', '')) for a in a]
```

The mistake that you got is you define "i" not "a", so you need to replace "i" to "a" OR

```
[int(i.replace(',', '')) for i in a]
```

The Exception comes out because you define "a" as a list (you didn't change a to a string)

Answer (score 2):

In the list comprehension, the item before 'for' is for each item in the final list. So, the manipulation has to be done on that item only. Each item is a string containing ',' within it. So, first you should remove the ',' from the item. And then convert the resulting string into a number:

```
a = [int(i.replace(',', '')) for i in a]
```

Comment: In code like this, I try to explain, or at least include links, about the various small parts.  For example, a new coder, might not understand that `in` is for containmainment.  Thanks for adding a blurb.  You can flag my comment as no longer need, after you see it.